# to get response from soap webservice through javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in javascript, I want to use SOAP web services in  am trying to get response from soap webservice through javascript code.
I am not able to get the response.I have enabled CROSS ORGIN RESOURCE SHARING option. I can't seem to figure out what's the reason behind. I tried the code with various changes,yet no response. Can anyone help me in figuring out the issue?
Please give me suggestions

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function soap(divname) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open('GET', 'soapurl', true);
            var sr =
                 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                '<soapenv:Envelope ' + 
                    'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
     'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:siperian.api">' +
   '<soapenv:Header/>' +
   '<soapenv:Body>' +
      '<urn:get>' +
         '<urn:username>admin</urn:username>' +
         '<urn:password>'+
            '<urn:password>admin</urn:password>'+
            '<urn:encrypted>false</urn:encrypted>'+
         '</urn:password>'+
         '<urn:orsId>sid-orsname</urn:orsId>'+

         '<urn:siperianObjectUid>PACKAGE.PKG_IDD_PARTY</urn:siperianObjectUid>'+
         '<urn:recordKey>'+
            '<urn:rowid>120002</urn:rowid>'+
         '</urn:recordKey>'+
         '<urn:recordTypes>'+
            '<urn:package>true</urn:package>'+
            '<urn:xref>false</urn:xref>'+
            '<urn:pendingXref>false</urn:pendingXref>'+
            '<urn:deletedXref>false</urn:deletedXref>'+
            '<urn:history>false</urn:history>'+
            '<urn:xrefHistory>false</urn:xrefHistory>'+
            '<urn:raw>false</urn:raw>'+
         '</urn:recordTypes>'+
         '<urn:returnTrustScores>false</urn:returnTrustScores>'+
         '<urn:returnLineage>false</urn:returnLineage>'+
      '</urn:get>'+
   '</soapenv:Body>'+
'</soapenv:Envelope>';
/*
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        alert(xmlhttp.response);
                    }
                }
            }
  */          // Send the POST request
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
            xmlhttp.send(sr);
  }
  function myFunction(xmlhttp) {
  var x = document.ggetElementsByTagName("rowid").innerHTML =
  xhttp.responseText;
  alert(x);

            // send request
            // ...
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Soap" onclick="soap(test);" />
   <div id="test"> Result </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The fi rst thing I would do is test if you can even get a response from the endpoint you are calling. Try sending the request with a tool like Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) and see if you get a result. Secondly, the syntax of your function myFunction doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: once the webservice is invoked , in my function i am trying to parse the xml tag rowid, i just tried it. As i told i am new to javascript. Excuse me for my silly mistakes. Please give your valuable suggestions